# prove no identity element in the given Cayley Table of three elements

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, magma, cayley-table

Prove that the operation in the following Cayley table has no identity element:

$$
\begin{array}{c|ccc}
\hline
* & u & v & w \\
\hline
u & u & w & w \\
v & v & v & v \\
w & w & u & v \\
\hline
\end{array}
$$
The only way I can think is just by checking it one by one. But I don't think that be considered a proof.

Comment: For such a small table, and considering the problem's aim to get you familiar with identities, "just checking each one" is probably *exactly* what you should do. It certainly *does* qualify as proof. It's unlikely such a small example would yield a worthwhile fancy proof.

Comment: You sound a bit like a pirate.

Answer (score 2):

Since there are only three elements, you can certainly "just" check each case. Indeed, that's exactly what you should probably do: "Proof by cases" is a perfectly legitimate method of proof:

Consider each element as a separate "case" (there are only three to consider). For ***each*** element $x \in \{u, v, w\}$, find a counterexample which shows that $x$ cannot be the identity.

For example, suppose we test the case where $x = w$: From the table, we have that $w*w = v.\;$ This means $w$ *cannot* be an identity, since if $x = w$ *were* the identity, we must have $w \times w = w$. $\;\checkmark$

Do the same for each of $u$ and $v$, and you're done.

---

One observation, as noted below in the comments: See if you can prove that if an identity element $x$ exists, we would need to have one column for element $x$ replicate the left-most column, and the corresponding row for $x$ replicate the top most row, the "header" row.

Example where there exists an identity element $u$:

$$
\begin{array}{l}
\text{Example with identity u} \\
\begin{array}{c|ccc}
\hline
* & u & v & w \\
\hline
u & u & v & w \\
v & v & w & u \\
w & w & u & v \\
\hline
\end{array}
\end{array}
$$

Comment: ok thanks. I'll just do it case by case

Comment: I think that the observation at the end is the better answer and is probably what was expected.

Answer (score 0):

I will in a way just reword the second part of the other answer by amWhy.

You notice the identity element from a Cayley table, if there is one, because in this case the line **and** the column of the table labeled by that element both show the identity function on the underlying set (not just a bijection).

In your example
$$
\begin{array}{c|ccc}
\hline
* & u & v & w \\
\hline
u & \color{red}{u} & w & w\\
v & \color{red}{v} & v & v\\
w & \color{red}{w} & u & v\\
\hline
\end{array}
$$
no line shows $u,v,w$ in this order while the column in red, labeled by $u$, does. Indeed here $u$ is a **right-identity** only and not a left identity.

Pay attention because if an identity element exists, than it is unique; instead left and right identity elements may exist and not be unique. Further:

- if one identity element exists, than no other element can be a left nor right identity;
- if two or more left (right) identities exist, than no element can be a right (left) identity.